# Windows Task Scheduler skips a scheduled interval

Tags: scheduled-task, task-scheduler

We use Windows Task Scheduler on Win2008/R2 to run a small Powershell job every 15 minutes.  It creates a small XML file which triggers a BizTalk process to run, so it typically takes under 1 second to run.

A week ago, it skipped two consecutive intervals, such as 3:00 and 3:15am.  All other intervals ran as normal.  Any idea of how this could happen, and what I might look for.  This is based on looking at the history of the job.

This history has now rolled off, but I have a screen shot that I saved: 
[image]

You can see from above it ran at 2:45 and not again until 3:29 (about 3:30).

Comment: Anything in the "Conditions" or "Settings" tab of the scheduled task?  Any chance you've Windows Updates configured to run during that time?  You may want to look in the Event Viewer to see what else was going on.

Comment: Excellent idea, but nothing interesting there. I looked, and nothing in App Event Log except some SQL timeouts at 3:05-3:07.  Nothing in System log nor Setup log.